# duplicate messages with same JMS correlationID

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic, message-queue, spring-jms

I have a Application where a message(with specific **correlation ID**) is placed in a topic with four subscribers.When a message is placed it is consumed by 4 subscribers and they are placing the reply with the same correlation id to a queue(reply=4messages).Now I have a doubt that when  messages are having **duplicate correlation id**. How will  the consumer know which message to consume when it is searching for the message with correlation id placed in the request?

Comment: Interesting scenario. What is the reason for all subscribers processing the same message and providing reply? Do each subscriber process the message differently?

Comment: No,they do not process the message differently.They process it in same manner(that is the issue I posted this question).Not sure,why it was written to broadcast to a topic.

Comment: Looks like the idea was to have load balancing across multiple subscribers where in only one of the subscribers will process the message and respond.

Answer (score 1):

There is no inherent problem with duplicate JMSCorrelationIDs. The consumer interested in the responses generally creates a consumer with a selector (i.e. JMSCorrelationID = 'ID-XXX...'). That consumer will match all messages that contain messages with the specified correlation id.

If you need to process each of the four responses separately, you'll need to define a convention where a custom message property determines which messages is from which original topic subscriber.

Comment: Thanks Matt for the reply.But I've observed that only one out of 4 messages are being consumed.Other 3 remains in queue forever.Is it the FCFS way the message is consumed?

Comment: Since all subscribers are replying, there will be four replies in the reply queue. Your application that is processing reply messages is just processing the first reply and leaving out others on the queue.

Comment: Yes Shashi, I observed that from my application.I just want to know if there are  any technical pubs referring to this implementation.

Comment: It's your application implementation specific. There is nothing messaging provider specific here.So no publications available. Ask the person who designed your application that way.